# Does the Japanese word for "love" have different connotations than it does in America?

Tags: translation, word-choice, english-to-japanese

I've been watching a lot of anime lately, and in nearly all the anime where a character proclaims that they "love" another character, I am confident that an American in the same situation would say they have a crush on someone or that they "like" someone, rather than "love".

I doubt this is a simple translation mistake, as it's consistently occurred in at least a dozen different anime.

So, in Japan, can "love" mean something slightly different, maybe something along the lines of "I'm attracted to you and I want to become closer to you"?

Comment: Can you point to an example of this dialogue in Japanese? It's difficult to tell what you mean by the word "love" without the original Japanese.

Comment: though I'd guess you were talking about the word 好き if it's in confession scenes.

Comment: @agnesi Sorry, I don't know any specific instances off the top of my head, but I can try to find some.  It'll take a while to locate them though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct equivalent of "love" is **愛** (*ai*) in Japanese, and this is a very big word — perhaps even bigger than English "love". English people often say "I love pizza", "I love New York" and so on, but Japanese people very rarely use 愛 with inanimate things. Even between two people, 愛 is generally thought to be something they gradually gain months after beginning a romantic relationship. Some western people living in Japan use 愛 too casually, which sometimes even embarrasses Japanese people.

There is another word, **恋** (*koi*), which can also be translated as *love*. "I fell in love with someone (at first sight)" is 恋に落ちた, not 愛に落ちた. See: [Love in the air: 愛ｘ恋 {あい vs こい}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2246/5010) However, 恋 still is a bit literary word; we do not say 恋 out loud very often when gossiping. When people casually say "You have a thing for her?" or "He has a crush on her", 恋 rarely appears, either.

Instead, **好き** (*suki*) is used all the time in such casual conversations, and this word literally means *to like*. This is a very handy expression; in a situation where English speakers may say "I'm in love with him", Japanese people often get away with just using 好き.

So in conclusion, the concept of *love* is different in Japanese; there are at least three common words to refer to it. You seem to feel Japanese people overuse the word *love*, but I feel it's the other way around. Japanese people do not frequently use 愛 or 恋 in "girl talks", so it's probably the translators who needs to add the word *love* to make sentences more natural to the English-speaking audience.

I think this article is good: [KOKUHAKU: JAPAN'S "LOVE CONFESSING" CULTURE](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/kokuhaku-love-confessing-japan/)

Comment: Excellent!  Your answer and the "Kokuhaku" article cleared things up wonderfully!  Thank you!